# Tooltip on the favorite button for questions seems wrong.

Tags: bug, bookmarks

Below the arrows for up- and downvoting questions we have the star to make questions favorites and see how many users did so. When I didn't click the star but somebody else did, the tooltip reads:

> This is a favorite question. (Click again to undo)

This seems misleading since clicking it won't undo anything, it will make it a favorite question for me as well.

The tooltip even says the same when nobody chose to make it a favorite question. In this case 'This is a favorite question.' is just wrong.

Comment: Perhaps a solution would be as simple as to let it say "Mark as a favourite question (click again to undo)" in place of "This is ...".

Comment: As long as the tooltip is the same for different situations, this might be the best way to go. Making the tooltip depend on wether or not it is a favorite question (of mine) would be better though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is telling you what having the star marked by your click is supposed to signify, not stating the current status.  The same format applies to hovering over the uparrows and downarrows.  The description applies (if at all) only when the star (or arrow) is highlighted by you having clicked it.

It is not wrong, but it is potentially confusing.  Lord_Farin suggests in a comment a clearer alternative, replacing "This is..." with "Mark as...".  I don't see a need for changing the description when you click, because the button itself changes to indicate whether or not it is clicked.

Comment: "this comment adds something useful to the post"

Comment: In the context of all other tooltips that also state what is signified by clicking what I'm hovering, this makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

I am in favor of keeping the current description, because it is consistent with the hovertext on the up/down vote arrows.

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

is shorter and more to the point than

> "click this arrow to mark that the question shows research effort, is useful and clear"

The hovertext is not a statement that SE makes (after all, the question could be total garbage), it's the statement that you can make by clicking.

SE uses the same approach for downvotes, and for comment votes: the hovertext directly describes what  clicking that page element means.

> (Click again to undo) This seems misleading since clicking it won't undo anything

Clearly, your first click on something is not  clicking it **again**.